# All records are in the first cell of excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, txt

I have a .txt file with this content:

```
order-id    order-item-id   purchase-date   payments-date   buyer-email buyer-name  payment-method-details  cpf ship-county buyer-phone-number  sku product-name    quantity-purchased  currency    item-price  item-tax    shipping-price  shipping-tax    ship-service-level  recipient-name  ship-address-1  ship-address-2  ship-address-3  ship-city   ship-state  ship-postal-code    ship-country    ship-phone-number   delivery-start-date delivery-end-date   delivery-time-zone  delivery-Instructions   is-business-order   purchase-order-number   price-designation
701-0760000-5410044 00083400045170  2022-06-25T15:16:44+00:00   2022-06-25T15:16:44+00:00   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@marketplace.amazon.com.br   Everton Everton da Everton  Other   000.000.000-01  Cidade Cidade       000000132046310000  Fogão Fogão 5 Bocas De Fogão Cor Inox Com Mesa De Fogão E Touch Timer Com Autodesligamento - 0YS5000 110V   1   BRL 1119.00 0.00    101.90  0.00    Standard    Everton Everton da Everton  Rua das Ruas Ruas 111   Apartamento 11 Cidade Cidade        São José dos Josés  PR  11135111    BR                      false
```

So I use these codes:

```
import pandas as pd
text_file = pd.read_csv('./file.txt')
text_file.to_csv('new_file_name.csv')
```

However, all records of the generated .csv file are in the first cells only:
[image: Imagem]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your "problem" is that pandas expect a more clear separation, normally a single space is a bad idea (What if your header naturally includes a space?) So, normally pandas expect a comma or a semicolon or something more definitive.
However, you can use the `sep` param to define your own delimiter, or use `delim_whitespace=True`

Untested, but should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
text_file = pd.read_csv('./file.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
text_file.to_csv('new_file_name.csv')
```

Comment: I got the .txt content like this, with spaces instead of commas. I tried your code and it didn't work, still in the first cell.

Comment: I just noticed your code has variable spacing, meaning sometimes theres 3 spaces and other times 4. 
Instead of the `sep` param, try this: `delim_whitespace=True`

Let me know if it works and ill edit the post.

Comment: The result has changed a little but all records are still in the first cell: https://prnt.sc/MyQY3SiSS3R-

Comment: That's just excel/your CSV viewer. It "only" accepts semi-colons as delimiters. I've tried it an online CSV viewer and it works fine. HOWEVER, you should really consider editing the input file to a proper format, especially because your actual values include spaces. 

Include a few lines that changes any multiple spaces to commas or semicolons.